# Windows 10 - Movies&TV app doesn't play videos, Groove doesn't play music

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, video-playback

Sorry if this sounds insane, but I've been trying to research this issue for over a month with no results, either the answers I get are from microsoft saying to "reinstall the app" (done several times to no avail) or from Reddit saying to simply install a different app (which doesn't actually *solve the problem*)

Getting to the point: Starting about two months ago, the Movies&TV app would simply give me a black player when trying to play any video files (not frozen, or a true "black screen", simply the player itself has a black display), and Groove music will open with nothing playing and then freeze after trying to play music. The issue goes away after restarting my computer, but only stays 'fixed' for a random period of time between a few hours, to 4 days before going back to not working.

I've tried:

- Scanning for Malware *multiple* times, using McAffe, Windows Defender, and MalwareBytes and gotten clean results from all three every time.
- re-installing the codec packs
- installing k-lite codec pack
- re-installing Movies&TV and Groove
- Updating drivers
- Updating Windows
- Rolling back to old drivers *and* rolling back to old Windows versions.

None of these have fixed anything, and I'm running out of options to try short of a factory reset, and even that I'm skeptical of. I'm using a pretty recent HP laptop, so I could always send it it, but I'd like to avoid that too if I can help it.

Any advice would be more than welcome!

Edit: I should add, I have tried launching in safe mode, and much like restarting and launching in normal, videos and music play, but only for that window of time mentioned earlier, before not working again.

Comment: [HEVC Video Extensions from Device Manufacturer](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/9N4WGH0Z6VHQ?hl=en-us&gl=us) might solve your problem, it’s also free and published by Microsoft so you have nothing to lose. I would definitely remove k-lite codecs, and whatever codecs, you refer to as “codecs”. Would be interesting to know if it behavior happens while in safe mode. [Edit] your question to clarify that test case. That link should still work, and it works on a Windows box obviously, otherwise you can’t install it.

Comment: *ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq*, pasted in a browser should work (same application as the other link but the link is significantly older). Link only works in the US by the way

Comment: Thanks for the links Ramhound! I was already aware of this link, and it's already installed. Couldn't figure out how to un/reinstall the HEVC Video Extensions from the store.

As for the other "codecs" you mentioned, it's just the recommended stuff from K-lite. After it didn't fix anything, I had already uninstalled it, but thank you for the advice!

Comment: Also.. FYI Knight.. the codec stuff has plagued Windows for many years.  When all else fails, use [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/en/downloads) or [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html).  All of the codecs are built in. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Only moderators and the authors of deleted comments can see them.  So, I have no idea if any comments have been deleted.  Even people that are not able to answer the question will prompt you to improve your question.  I am deleting mine as its target comment was deleted.